# Soaked chia seeds do not swell as expected

Tags: soaking, chia

I soaked chia seeds in milk overnight and kept them in the fridge. The next morning I did not find them very swelled.

What can I do to improve this.

Comment: Can you add more info? How old were the seeds? Why do you think they did not swell enough (and how much is that exactly)?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the *seeds* did not look like they had swelled. While the seed itself looks like its size stays about the same, the "swelling" really comes from the fiber soaking up liquid, forming a gelatinous "blob" around each seed pod.

[image: soaked chia seeds in their own gel]

And how much they swell will also depend on how much liquid they're soaking in. This is a [time-lapse video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKMMdblicuA) of chia seeds swelling as they soak in water.

But always better safe than sorry: If you don't feel comfortable eating what you've made because you don't think it reacted properly, discard it and try again with a different batch. The more you experiment with chia seeds, the more you'll know what behavior to expect from them.

Comment: I bought the roasted Chia seeds and I saoked them in the milk. Should i try water? Also, the milk is sufficient enough in which Chia seeds are soaked

Comment: They should soak equally well in milk as in water. However, I've never tried soaking _roasted_ chia seeds, so I don't know what to expect from that.